# Is there a better way to fetch an API on Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Yesterday I was working on a project because I am learning Angular by myself. I tried to make an API call to PokeAPI because I wanted to fetch the .svg for a Pokemon and its name. I made it work, but I do not really know if this can be improved and make something better.

I am providing all the code (since it is a very little program) and a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-muhdep?file=src/app/app.component.html) example for testing purposes.

**pokemon.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PokemonService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getRandomPokemon(id: number) {
    return this.http.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`);
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<img src="{{ image }}" width="300" height="300">
<h2>
  {{ actualPokemon }}
</h2>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PokemonService } from './services/pokemon.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'RandomPokemon';
  actualPokemon = '';
  image = '';

  constructor(private pokemonService: PokemonService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getRandomPokemon();
    // console.log(this.actualPokemon);
  }
  
  getRandomPokemon() {
    this.pokemonService.getRandomPokemon(Math.floor(Math.random() * 807) + 1).subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        this.actualPokemon = data.name;
        this.image = data.sprites.other.dream_world.front_default;
        console.log(this.actualPokemon);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

I have imported HttpClientModule in **app.module.ts** but I will not paste it here because it is just a dependency.

Comment: Trying to avoid any opnion based answer, to me this looks fine.

Comment: You can share your opinion in a constructive way

Comment: Of course, but there's nothing to say about that. It's the correct way to make an API call in thie case. The async pipe wouldn't really fit this time, since you are saving some data instead of just displaying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that is a very general http request, if any error is fired from your side, you won't even understand why it is failing. I Do not recommend making this kind of request to backend. You want to control data as much as possible

- no `response type` specified
- no `observe: response` specified
- no response serializer
- no interface for response data
- no error handling

It has absolutely nothing, its just a plain request.

somewhat decent request would look like

```
getRandomPokemon(id: number): Observable<Pokemon> {
   const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('content-type', 'application/json');

   return this.http.get<Pokemon>(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`, { headers: headers, observe: "response" })
   .pipe(
    catchError((err) => {
      // throw error to observer and treat it in subscription
      return throwError(() => new Error(err));
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: You dont have to set headers to the call because the documentation doesnt require them.

Comment: I was talking about the PokeAPI, but you are 100% right. Thankyou